# Get cluster members/elements clustering with scikit-learn DBSCAN

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I use dbscan scikit-learn algorithm for clustering.
db = DBSCAN().fit(X) returns me 8 for example. My goal is to recover the cluster by cluster components. I said that X is a vector to vector and what I expect when I speak of cluster members, it is the sub-vectors of X.
Is there anyone to help me?

Comment: Please clarify your question. But I guess you look for the labels of your points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are asking for the cluster assignment of each item in your dataset, X.

You can use the labels_ attribute. `db.labels_` Each index here corresponds to the same index in X, so you can see the assignments.

Comment: To be more clear.
Let's take for example X (x1, x2, x3, x4) with x1 = [0,0,0,1,0,1], x2 = [0,0,0,0,1,0], etc. When I write  db = DBSCAN().fit (X), I want to recover for each cluster its sub-vectors xi. In addition when I do                  clusters = [X [db.labels_ == i] for i in xrange (n_clusters_)], I get an error of the kind "only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index." If dbscan algorithm Does not allow me to get cluster element, with what algorithm of clustering can i do it?

Comment: @PascalOuedraogo X[db.labels_ ==i] returns an array with more than one element. Instead you could loop through your n_clusters_ and create a different array for each. Personally, I would make a dictionary mapping the cluster number to the list: cluster_dict = {i: X[db.lables==i] for i in xrange(n_clusters_)}